# How to use PathPattern in order to create DeepLink Apps Android?

Tags: android, deep-linking, permalinks

I have read documentation about create an deeplink and use app linking service in android studio 3.0. its pretty simple and easy to understand, but I have little bit problem when my URL has no prefix path. example :

```
https://example.com/<this is my premalink>/amp
```

there is no prefix, its directly url pattern.
when i use regex

```
^[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*$
```

it doesnt works, error shown as

```
The URL doesnt map to any activity
```

when i use only star, like :

```
https://example.com/*/amp
```

its show seem error. i got stuck in this step, I've check much tutorial about deeplink, and there always use pathPrefix instead of pathPattern.

Answer (score 12):

It's a common drawback in android deep linking that it only support `*` and `.` regex character. It's mentioned in [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element#path) and [can be observed in source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/os/PatternMatcher.java).

From docs:

> For more information on these three types of patterns, see the
> descriptions of PATTERN_LITERAL, PATTERN_PREFIX, and
> `PATTERN_SIMPLE_GLOB` in the PatternMatcher class.

PATTERN_SIMPLE_GLOB is for regex and it says only match

> Pattern type: the given pattern is interpreted with a
> simple glob syntax for matching against the string it is tested against.
> In this syntax, you can use the `'*'` character to match against zero or
> more occurrences of the character immediately before.  If the
> character before it is `'.'` it will match any character.  The character
> `'\'` can be used as an escape.  This essentially provides only the '*'
> wildcard part of a normal regexp.
>
> `public static final int PATTERN_SIMPLE_GLOB = 2;`

So only `*`, `.` and `\` are allowed. Usage of other pattern literal `+,?` etc; will result in failure.

Either you can use your working option or you can use

```
https://example.com/./....*
```

`....*` at least 3 characters then `.*` mean 0 or more characters

```
<activity
    android:name="packagename.ActivityName" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http"
              android:host="www.example.com"
              android:pathPattern="/./....*" />
        <!-- note that the leading "/" is required for pathPrefix-->
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Thankyou for answering my question, but when i fill my pathpattern value with your example. /*/...*
there still shown seem error.
here is my sample link : https://technologue.id/kemenperin-bangun-ekosistem-digital-songsong-industri-4-0/amp/
is there any java code that i must add to make it works? thankyou

Comment: you need `/.*/.../` or  `/.*/amp/`

Comment: thank you! great to see the Android Studio Links Assistent says the pattern could be [a-z]+ xD

Comment: How do I use this for files of some extension ? Example "*.abc"?

Comment: There's a new option for API 31 - pathAdvancedPattern mentioned here -https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element#path

It supports more regexp operators.