# Using Android deeplinking with the end of URL

Tags: android, deep-linking, intentfilter

I want to put deep linking with all the link looking like this :

```
https://myapp.com/*/*/quiz.html
```

How can I do that ? I try this `intent-filter` in my Manifest but the pathPrefix is not working :

```
 <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https"
                      android:host="myapp.com"
                      android:pathPrefix="/.*/.*/quiz\\.html"/>
 </intent-filter>
```

Without the `android:pathPrefix` it's working but it's opening all the links from `https://myapp.com`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `android:pathPattern` in your data element.

```
<data
     android:host="myapp.com"
     android:pathPattern="/.*/.*/quiz.html"
     android:scheme="https" />
```

Then you can set any url pattern you want to open in your app. Read [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element#path) . Also, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52436376/7530555) is good explanation about how it works.