# pattern matching in Android links assistant

Tags: android, android-app-links

I am trying to do something I thought was going to be simple, but is turning out to be a nightmare. I am trying to use the App Links Assistant in Android Studio to have my app automatically open when a user goes to a specific URL. Since I can't really post my real address or anything I will just use an example URL. What I need is for the app to open when someone visits the url with a path of numbers, example: `http://example.com/654876192` it will always be /[numbers] and there will always be 9 of them.

So I open the App Links Assistant in Android studio and add a new entry for a website `http://example.com` and then for the "Path" option I chose `pathPattern` and for the value I use `/[0-9]+` That should, in theory match the above URL, however below that section there is a place where you can type in a URL to see if it will match and nothing I put in there actually matches.

Is there something I am missing, does the `pathPattern` not actually work? Am I doing the pattern wrong? I really have no idea why it isn't matching.

[image]

You can see from the screenshot it says that url will not match. Please help, thank you.

Edit: here is the full intent filter from the android manifest...

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="meet.finitycare.com"
                    android:pathPattern="/[0-9]+" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Please add in the full `<intent-filter>` section to your question. Without the [data element](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element) we can't see what the Android manifest rules are.

Comment: `android:pathPattern` isn't standard regexp. See: [How to use PathPattern in order to create DeepLink Apps Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52436111/295004)